# how to process data generated by ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, imagedata

I am trying to use Keras ImageDataGenerator to train my model with a large stereo Dataset.

For each scene, I have two rgb images, I have to split them and concatenate them to have 6 one-channel images as an input of my model (i.e. this shape (6,224,224,1)). For small datasets, it is easy because I can upload the two sub-datasets in the memory and process the concatenation of images as ndarrays. But with ImageDataGenerator, it is not the same, as I have to make sure that it takes the same batches from the two sub-datasets, and be able to process the concatenation before passing the input to my model.

Inspired from this [post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8130,), I tried this code:

```
input_imgen = ImageDataGenerator()

def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, batch_size):
    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(directory=dir1,
                                          color_mode="rgb",
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          class_mode="categorical",
                                          shuffle=False)



    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(directory=dir2,
                                          color_mode="rgb",
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          class_mode="categorical",
                                          shuffle=False)
    while True:
            X1i = genX1.next()
            X2i = genX2.next()
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]
```

In my case, how could I process the two series X1i[0] and X2i[0] with batches of images of size( 224,224,3) to have X1Sum of size(6,224,224), and instead of:
    yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1] 
I will have:
    yield X1Sum, X2i[1]

Comment: Can't you do `np.concatenate(X1i, X2i)` and reshape ? I am guessing `X1i` and `X2i` have shapes `(224, 224, 3)` each. Or am i wrong in my assumption?

Comment: X1i and  X2i are series of images of size (224, 224, 3), I am not sure that I can do np.concatenate(list(X1i), list(X2i)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you can simply convert the list to arrays and then use `np.concatenate` to merge the channels and `np.swapaxes` to put the channels in front. Example code with output:

```
import numpy as np

list_a = []
list_b = []

for i in range(5):
    list_a.append(np.random.rand(4, 4, 3))
    list_b.append(np.random.rand(4, 4, 3))

a = np.array(list_a)
b = np.array(list_b)
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=-1)
print(c.shape)
c = np.swapaxes(c, 0, -1)
print(c.shape)
```

Output is:

```
(5, 4, 4, 3)
(5, 4, 4, 3)
(5, 4, 4, 6)
(6, 4, 4, 5)
```

I guess this is what you want to do.